# ASP.NET Custom Error Page Not Displayed for Abnormal URLs

Tags: asp.net, iis-7

A vulnerability scanning service regularly tests our site for PCI scan compliance. It has just started trying to access URLs with abnormal formatting, such as:

http://www.mydomain.com/ShoppingCart.aspx//ErrorPage.aspx%3fid%3d2?

We have a Custom Error Page set which works for everything except this. Is there any way to force IIS to display it for this type of URL?

**The Error:** Runtime Error - An application error occurred on the server....

**We're using:**

- ASP.NET 2.0 (Framework 3.5)
- IIS 7.0 (Windows Server Web 2008)

I've tried to debug this, but I can't reproduce this on IIS 6.0.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There might be a more simple solution, but if you're on IIS7 you can use [URL Rewrite](http://www.iis.net/download/URLRewrite) to match those type of URLs and map them back to your error page.

Comment: I still can't reproduce the problem -- even on our production system, but our scanning service isn't reporting the issue anymore. Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0):

The `%3f` part isn't being parsed by IIS 7 and so it can't find the page.  If you look in your site logs you'll probably see some 404's.

You'll need to configure IIS 7 to point to your errorpage.aspx file as it's default 404 page.

Comment: I tried this but it didn't seem to work. Thanks for your answer though!